# How do I retrieve data from a Django DB before sending off Celery task to remote worker?

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, distributed-computing

I have a celery `shared_task` that is scheduled to run at certain intervals. Every time this task is run, it needs to first retrieve data from the Django DB in order to complete the calculation. This task may or may not be sent to a celery worker that is on a separate machine, so in the celery task I can't make any queries to a local celery database.

So far I have tried using signals to accomplish it, since I know that functions with the wrapper `@before_task_publish` are executed before the task is even published in the message queue. However, I don't know how I can actually get the data to the task.

```
@shared_task
def run_computation(data):
    perform_computation(data)


@before_task_publish.connect
def receiver_before_task_publish(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
   data = create_data()
   # How do I get the data to the task from here?
```

Is this the right way to approach this in the first place? Or would I be better off making an API route that the celery task can get to retrieve the data?

Comment: If the data is serializable (i.e., can be converted into simple text representation), then you can pass it as arguments to the task when you call it. If it's not, then you can't pass it directly, and you need to come up with a way for the task to fetch the necessary data (e.g., via an API).

Comment: @solarissmoke The data is serializable, in fact the function I call is what serializes it. The thing I am confused about is how to run the function that serializes the data before the task is put into the queue by the celery beat scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the solution that worked for me, thanks for the help @solarissmoke.
What works best for me is utilizing Celery "chain" callback functions and separate RabbitMQ queues for designating what would be computed locally and what would be computed on the remote worker.
My solution looks something like this:

```
@app.task
def create_data_task():
   # this creates the data to be passed to the analysis function
   return create_data()

@app.task
def perform_computation_task(data):
   # This performs the computation with given data
   return perform_computation(data)

@app.task
def store_results(result):
   # This would store the result in the DB here, but for now we just print it
   print(result)

@app.task
def run_all_computation():
   task = signature("path.to.tasks.create_data_task", queue="default") | signature("path.to.tasks.perform_computation_task", queue="remote_computation") | signature("path.to.tasks.store_results", queue="default") 
   task()
```

Its important to note here that these tasks were not run serially; they were in fact separate tasks that are run by the workers and therefore do not block a single thread. The other tasks are only activated by a callback function from the others. I declared two celery queues in RabbitMQ, a default one called default, and one specifically for remote computation called "remote_computation". This is described explicitly [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/routing.html?highlight=routing%20tasks#queue.bind) including how to point celery workers at created queues.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify the task data in place, from the `before_task_publish` handler, so that it gets passed to the task. I will say upfront that there are [many reasons](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html) why this is not a good idea:

```py
@before_task_publish.connect
def receiver_before_task_publish(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    data = create_data()
    # Modify the body of the task data. 
    # Body is a tuple, the first entry of which is a tuple of arguments to the task. 
    # So we replace the first argument (data) with our own.
    body[0][0] = data
    # Alternatively modify the kwargs, which is a bit more explicit
    body[1]['data'] = data
```

This works, but it should be obvious why it's risky and prone to breakage. Assuming you have control over the task call sites I think it would be better to drop the signal altogether and just have a simple function that does the work for you, i.e.,:

```py
def create_task(data):
    data = create_data()
    run_computation.delay(data)
```

And then in your calling code, just call `create_task(data)` instead of calling the task directly (which is what you presumably do right now).